# Not sure how to use async so asking

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Ok so I am wanting to pull from two different collections. I am using Express and mongodb.  If I use one or the other collection it works fine and I know I cant just combine the two finds like this: (forgive me ... this is just an example.)

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  User.findById(req.user._id, (err, user) => {
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    Item.find({}, (err, allItems) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      res.render("products", { items: allItems });
    });
  });
});
```

I know I need to use async but I am not sure how to set this up.  If anyone is willing to help I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: First off, you should be returning when you handle those errors. Also, are you referring to the module `async`? (If so, there's `async.parallel` for that very purpose.)

Comment: Yes the module async

Comment: Check out the docs for [1.5.x](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md#parallel) or [2.x](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel) (depending on the version you use). They give examples that could be easily altered to what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Db calls are asynchronous by nature. But You can use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to combine the result of asynchronous calls.

```
'use strict';

router.get("/", (req, res) => {

  Promise.all([
    User.findById(req.user._id),
    Item.find({})
  ]).then(results => {
    let [userDetails, items] = results;
    return res.render("products", {
      items: items,
      user: userDetails
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('err', err.stack);
  });

});
```